# Edit text android studio

Tags: android-studio

When I tried to increase the height, the hint for edit text aligns to the center of the height. How can I make an edit text as below?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add minHeight to increase the height of the editText and set gravity="start"

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Android Studio, this is because of idea Vim for my case. And you can switch from this mode (uneditable) by clicking "i" on your keyboard.